# ASP.NET MVC: how to authorize for users or client IP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I'd like for certain controllers to only be accessible to authorized users.  AuthorizeAttribute works great for this.  However, I'd also like those controllers to provide access to certain IP numbers even if the remote user is unauthorized.  Should I override AuthorizeAttribute to provide this functionality, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instincts are correct--extending authorize attribute makes the most sense in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that if you add both the `AuthorizeAttribute` with users and your own `ClientIPAuthorizeAttribute` with the client IP's, unauthorised users within the specified IP's still won't be allowed...

This is because individual `AuthorizeAttribute`s can't communicate with one another to do a logical `OR`. Subclassing is the easiest and cleanest way to achieve what you want.